# How can I pass datetime from API to postgresql db which receives timestamp without zone time?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postgresql, api, timestamp

I trying to pass a datetime value from MVC API net Core to PostgreSQL database.

In the model I'm using data type string for the datetime (fechahora) and the db has data type timestamp without zone time.

Model:

```
public class Feedback
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string fechahora { get; set; }
        public string detalle { get; set; }
    }
```

My function:

```
 public async Task<bool> InsertFeedback(Feedback feedback)
        {
            var db = dbConnection();
            var sql = @"INSERT INTO public.tb_feedback (fechahora,detalle)
                        VALUES @fechahora,@detalle";
            var result = await db.ExecuteAsync(sql, new { feedback.fechahora, feedback.detalle });
            return result > 0;
        }
```

If I execute the same query in the database it works.
Also if a consult using GET from postman works too
[GET postmand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqmE1.png)

but this happens when I try to
[POST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVGda.png)

The issue is directly with timestamp, because I have other controller all working fine with no dates.

Comment: Are you sure you're just not missing the brackets after VALUES: VALUES(@fechahora,@detaille)

Comment: thanks I was missing that but also the format had to be taken in count, found my solution after this tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, first I was missing the brackets but then I also added the to_timestamp and the correct format

```
var db = dbConnection();
            var sql = @"INSERT INTO public.tb_feedback (fechahora,detalle)
                        VALUES (to_timestamp(@fechahora,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),@detalle)";
            var result = await db.ExecuteAsync(sql, new { feedback.fechahora, feedback.detalle });
            return result > 0;
```

Json POST

```
{
    "fechahora": "02/05/2021 14:00:00",
    "detalle": "prueba"
}
```